# Initializer doesn't create instance in console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, initializer

I am new to ruby and I am trying to create a hangman game, to do so I need to create a new game each time the user click on a button.

First step is to create the same object each time the methode create will be called (it will be different because of the .sample.

I am trying to create an object with the initialize method in my model.rbfile.

Here is my code :

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :guesses

  def initialize(*)
    super
    @word_to_guess = word_to_guess
    @health_bar = 5
    @game_status = game_status
  end

  def word_to_guess
    words = [
      "spokesperson", "firefighter", "headquarters", "confession", "difficulty", "attachment", "mechanical",
      "accumulation", "hypothesis", "systematic", "attraction", "distribute", "dependence", "environment",
      "jurisdiction", "demonstrator", "constitution", "constraint", "consumption", "presidency", "incredible",
      "miscarriage", "foundation", "photography", "constituency", "experienced", "background", "obligation",
      "diplomatic", "discrimination", "entertainment", "grandmother", "girlfriend", "conversation", "convulsion",
      "constellation", "leadership", "insistence", "projection", "transparent", "researcher", "reasonable","continental",
      "excavation", "opposition", "interactive", "pedestrian", "announcement", "charismatic", "strikebreaker",
      "resolution", "professional", "commemorate", "disability", "collection", "cooperation", "embarrassment",
      "contradiction", "unpleasant", "retirement", "conscience", "satisfaction", "acquaintance", "expression",
      "difference", "unfortunate", "accountant", "information", "fastidious", "conglomerate", "shareholder",
      "accessible", "advertising", "battlefield", "laboratory", "manufacturer", "acquisition", "operational",
      "expenditure", "fashionable", "allocation", "complication", "censorship", "population", "withdrawal",
      "sensitivity", "exaggerate", "transmission", "philosophy", "memorandum", "superintendent", "responsibility",
      "extraterrestrial", "hypothesize", "ghostwriter", "representative", "rehabilitation", "disappointment",
      "understanding", "supplementary", "preoccupation"
          ]
    words.sample
  end

  def game_status
    game_status = ["Game not started yet", "In Game", "You win", "You loose"]
    game_status[0]
  end

end
```

The problem is that when I do a Game.new in console, it returns :

```
[1] pry(main)> Game.new
=> #<Game:0x00007fa79b613290 id: nil, word_to_guess: nil, health_bar: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, guesse_id: nil, game_status: nil>
```

So the instance is not created and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, instance was created

But I don't recommend to use instance variables such way. Instance variables are stored in memory

Also it's not good idea to override "getters" for rails attributes such way

It's better to store such data in database as rails attributes

You can do like this

```
after_initialize do
  self.word_to_guess ||= generate_word_to_guess
  self.health_bar ||= 5
  self.game_status ||= "Game not started yet"
end
```

Also it looks that for `health_bar` and `game_status` is better to define default values in database

You can read more about callbacks:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html